# How to count number of subdocuments with condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a mongoDB collection with documents like the one bellow. I want to cumulatively, over all documents, count how many subdocuments that the event field has, which is not null.

```
{
    name: "name1",
    events: {
        created: {
            timestamp: 1512477520951
        },
        edited: {
            timestamp: 1512638551022
        },
        deleted: null
    }
}



{
    name: "name2",
    events: {
        created: {
            timestamp: 1512649915779
        },
        edited: null,
        deleted: null
    }
}
```

So the result of the query on these two documents should return 3, because there are 3 events that is not null in the collection. I can not change the format of the document to have the event field be an array.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) from MongoDB 3.4.7 or greater in order to do this as an aggregation statement:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "total": {
      "$sum": {
        "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$events"
            },
            "cond": { "$ne": [ "$$this.v", null ] }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

That part is needed to look at the `"events"` object and translate each of the "key/value" pairs into array entries. In this way you can apply the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operation in order to remove the `null` "values" ( the `"v"` property ) and then use [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in order to count the matching list.

All of that is done under a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator

Or if you don't have a supporting version, you need mapReduce and JavaScript execution in order to to the same "object to array" operation:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    emit(null,
      Object.keys(this.events).filter(k => this.events[k] != null).length);
  },
  function(key,values) {
    return Array.sum(values);
  },
  { out: { inline: 1 } }
)
```

That uses the same basic process by obtaining the object keys as an array and rejecting those where the value is found to be `null`, then obtaining the `length` of the resulting array.

Because of the JavaScript evaluation, this is much slower than the aggregation framework counterpart. But it's really a question of what server version you have available to support what you need.